# How are $.ajax callbacks handled on the stack? (Firefox vs Chrome vs ... )

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

Good evening guys -

I've noticed that different browsers seem to handle callbacks differently.

As an example, Firefox seems to let an $.ajax.done({}) callback interrupt the current javascript instruction, but Chrome won't handle the $.ajax.done({}) callback until all current instructions finish. It's like Chrome sends the call to the end of an instruction **queue**, and Firefox adds it to the top of the instruction **stack**.

*(Bear in mind that this is probably entirely incorrect terminology - I really hope this is the right place to post this)*

Explicit Example that outlines my best guess:

```
function load_a_bunch_of_stuff()
    $.ajax({
        // ajax things here - e.g. load 10,000 whatevers from a server

    }).always(function() {
        ajaxStatus = "done!"
    });
}

function do_things_with_loaded_stuff() {
    // Loops as long as the status is "running" and the User is 
    // willing to retry:
    while (ajaxStatus === "running" && 
        confirm("Waiting on ajax, try again?"));

    // Do some cool stuff after the $.ajax call finishes
}

// --
// Main: (Assume do_things_with_loaded_stuff() is called before the 
//   load_a_bunch_of_stuff() finishes)

var ajaxStatus = "running";
load_a_bunch_of_stuff();
do_things_with_loaded_stuff();
```

-- My best guess --

In this example - the loop will run until Firefox lets the .always({}) change the 'ajaxStatus' to "done!" (probably while the user tries to click on OK) and then we can carry on.

However in Chrome, the .always({}) doesn't ever fire because (I'm guessing) the callback is executed **after** the current set of instructions finishes. In other words, since the .always({}) is added to the end of the instruction set (rather than in the next slot), it's stuck in the loop and never reaches the .always({}).

This example is just something similar to an issue I've ran into recently while trying to develop between the two browsers. Does anyone know if this interpretation is true?

Can anyone actually explain what's going on?

Comment: If you don't have the `confirm()` call, the callbacks will never be allowed to run.

Comment: Should `globalFlag` be `ajaxStatus`?

Comment: I reproduced this in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wmjeh8mo/

Comment: I think what you're seeing is that Firefox runs asynchronous code while it's waiting for you to respond to a `confirm()` dialog, but Chrome doesn't. I'm not sure whether this is specified or not, so you probably shouldn't depend on either way.

Comment: I've been trying to find any information about how modal prompts interact with the event loop, but none of my google searches have found anything.

Comment: Instead of using `confirm()`, I suggest you use an HTML dialog. If the user clicks on "Cancel", it can cancel the pending AJAX call. When the AJAX call completes, it can hide the dialog.

Comment: Firstly - yes, globalFlag was supposed to be ajaxStatus (I've changed it accordingly). Second - you're completely right in that the browser freezes without the confirm() (or alert()) statement! This is specifically what brought the issue to light - the two browsers unexpectedly seem to handle callbacks completely differently. -- Out of curiosity - did you get the same results in Fiddle?

Comment: A callback can never interrupt the regular Javascript code. The only difference is whether it can run during `confirm()`

Comment: May I add your fiddle link to the main post? It's emulating the problem really well on my end, and I think it'd help to get the point across to anyone else who's curious.

Comment: yes, feel free.

Comment: You could probably emulate it here with `setTimeout` in a stack snippet.

Comment: Here's a version using `setTimeout()`: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wmjeh8mo/1/

Comment: You're running setTimeout() on the ajax call? If you're still curious, I've come up with another solution that works for all browsers. I might post it later in its own post - check it out!  https://jsfiddle.net/dlahman/2g9dn6rv/3/

Comment: Thanks for your Help Barmar - your JSFiddle has shown that it isn't a callstack issue, but some issue with the way different browsers handle modal boxes. I guess it's some unintended glitch on Firefox's behalf. Honestly, I think it opens up more avenues for the browser than Chrome has at the moment.

Comment: `setTimeout` and AJAX are just different ways to run the callback function asynchronously. Both versions just show that Chrome doesn't run asynchronous actions while a modal box is displaying, but FF does.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for your help Barmar - I haven't seen this documented anywhere. Really interesting stuff.

Comment: I'll let you post the 'answer' if you'd like - your call!

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to AJAX, it's just about asynchronous code.

Firefox allows asynchronous callbacks to run while you're in a modal dialog from `confirm()`, `prompt()`, or `alert()`.  Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer don't.

This can be demonstrated using `setTimeout()`, it doesn't require `$.ajax`.

```js
function load_a_bunch_of_stuff() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ajaxStatus = "done";
  }, 3000);
}

function do_things_with_loaded_stuff() {
  // Loops as long as the status is "running" and the User is 
  // willing to retry:
  while (ajaxStatus === "running" &&
    confirm("Waiting on ajax, try again?"));
  $("div").text("Done");

}

var ajaxStatus = "running";
load_a_bunch_of_stuff();
do_things_with_loaded_stuff();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Running
</div>
```

Note that if you take out the `confim()` call, you should expect the loop to run infinitely on all browsers, since no Javascript engine should allow asynchronous callbacks to interrupt the main flow.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Barmar!